# How to populate a TableView using AFNetworking, CocoaPods and ObjectiveGumbo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have this code from a web site:

```
<div class="AspNet-GridView" id="ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_9872b464_b9b6_4c79_87b2_5f36cc169877_NewsGrid1">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="" class="NewsGrid">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="Infomobilita-Titolo" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_9872b464_b9b6_4c79_87b2_5f36cc169877$NewsGrid1','Sort$Title')">Titolo</a></th>
                        <th class="Infomobilita-Data" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_9872b464_b9b6_4c79_87b2_5f36cc169877$NewsGrid1','Sort$OrderByDate')">Data</a><img src="/_LAYOUTS/ATM/images/DownArrow.gif" style="border-width:0px;"></th>
                        <th class="Infomobilita-DataScadenza" scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_9872b464_b9b6_4c79_87b2_5f36cc169877$NewsGrid1','Sort$PublishingExpirationDate')">Data scadenza</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Titolo"><a href="/it/ViaggiaConNoi/InfoTraffico/Pagine/Lineebus40-72dal297spostamentodifermata.aspx">Linee bus 40-72: dal 29/7 spostamento di fermata</a></td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Data">29/07/2014</td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-DataScadenza">19/08/2014</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="AspNet-GridView-Alternate">
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Titolo"><a href="/it/ViaggiaConNoi/InfoTraffico/Pagine/Linea162dal2907modificadipercorso.aspx">Linea 162: dal 29/07 modifica di percorso</a></td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Data">29/07/2014</td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-DataScadenza">29/07/2015</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Titolo"><a href="/it/ViaggiaConNoi/InfoTraffico/Pagine/Lineatram12modificadipercorsodel010814.aspx">Linea tram 12: modifica di percorso del 01/08</a></td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Data">29/07/2014</td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-DataScadenza">01/08/2014</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="AspNet-GridView-Alternate">
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Titolo"><a href="/it/ViaggiaConNoi/InfoTraffico/Pagine/LineaM2dal267chiusaGessateBustraGorgonzolaeGessate.aspx">Linea M2: dal 26/7 chiusa Gessate. Bus tra Gorgonzola e Gessate</a></td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Data">28/07/2014</td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-DataScadenza">31/08/2014</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Titolo"><a href="/it/ViaggiaConNoi/InfoTraffico/Pagine/Linea566dall'18modificadipercorso.aspx">Linea 566: dall'1/8 modifica di percorso</a></td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-Data">28/07/2014</td>
                        <td class="Infomobilita-DataScadenza">19/08/2014</td>
                    </tr>
```

..and so on with other data.

I want to take the data of Titolo, Data and DataScandenza and put them in a table view.
How can I do that using AFNetworking, CocoaPods and ObjectiveGumbo?

I've already made this method, but I think there's something wrong:

```
    -(id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response data:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    OGDocument * document = [super responseObjectForResponse:response data:data error:error];

    NSArray * panels = [document select:@".AspNet-GridView"];

    NSMutableArray * articles = [NSMutableArray new];

    //The list of most read articles is in the second panel
    OGElement * list = (OGElement*)[panels[0] first:@"tr"];

    for (OGElement * listItem in [list select:@"td"])
    {
        OGElement * link = (OGElement*)[listItem first:@"a"];
        NSString * href = link.attributes[@"href"];
        NSString * title = [link.children[2] text];
        Article * article = [Article new];
        article.title = title;
        article.link = [NSURL URLWithString:href];
        [articles addObject:article];
    }

    return articles;
}
```

Please, someone helps me! :-) Thanks!

**EDIT:**

**I solved it!**

Here's how I did it. I modified the method in this way:

```
-(id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response data:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

{
    OGDocument * document = [super responseObjectForResponse:response data:data error:error];

```
 NSMutableArray * articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableArray * panels = [document select:@".Infomobilita-Titolo"];
```

// OGElement * list = (OGElement*)[panels[1] first:@"a"];
    [panels removeObjectAtIndex:0];

```
for (OGElement *file in panels) {

    OGElement *li = (OGElement*) [file first:@"a"];
    NSString * href = li.attributes [@"href"];
    NSLog(@"%@",href);
    NSString * title = [file.children[0] text];
    Article * article = [Article new];
    article.title = title;
    article.link = [NSURL URLWithString:href];
    [articles addObject:article];
    NSLog(@"%@",[file.children[0] text]);
}

return articles;
```

}

Comment: Might be better to use regex to parse data from HTML, you can find some info / tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/30288/nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet

Comment: Well, I didn't really know what ObjectiveGumbo is before I posted previous comment but it seems like it does something like that for you.